# Bootstrapping Monero blockchain via clearnet?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain-size

I have reasonably recent MacBookPro but the fans and CPU (Activity Monitor) are working hard.

I still have some blocks to sync:

[image]

Tried obtaining more info about the blockchain size:

- [How much time to have blockchain synced?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1572/how-much-time-to-have-blockchain-synced/1573)
- [Are criticisms of Monero's blockchain bloat substantiated?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/432/are-criticisms-of-moneros-blockchain-bloat-substantiated/457)
- https://moneroblocks.info/stats/blockchain-growth

**Ideally I'd like to bootstrap the blockchain in a fastest way possible.**

I have been using TOR in the past and there are some performance bottlenecks. I've never used I2P before but chances are there are some bottlenecks too.

Is there a clearnet version of Monero blockchain allowing me to get started reasonably fast?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the current bootstrap from [here](https://downloads.getmonero.org/blockchain.raw)

Regarding 'Monero's blockchain bloat' : As far as I know, until now the Monero BC network hasn't really experienced a problem due to this as it hasn't got to unbearable levels of traffic that suffer from the extra size that comes with RingCT.

Further, Monero will soon have [Bulletproofs](https://getmonero.org/2017/12/07/Monero-Compatible-Bulletproofs.html) which will reduce transaction size, improve transaction speed, and lower transaction fees